# Use of "up" in a sentence

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

Could you explain how "up" works in a sentence?

> 56' Derby County  1-0 West Brom
>
> McGoldrick does well to win the ball back **high up** the field before
> striking left-footed from 20 yards. Not far over.

Answer (score 2):

This is sense 4 from [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/up#Preposition)

> Further along (in any direction).

The direction is presumably implied here by the flow of the game, and *high* probably means "near the end of the field".

Comment: does "high" mean near in this context?

Comment: No, _high_ means "a long way up" . The metaphor is to regard one end of the field as the top, and then "up" means towards that end, and "high up" means a long way towards that end.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. That's clear now.